# using vncviewer passwd command but system still asks to input password

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

Using vncviewer passwd command in terminal but program still ask me to input password manually. How to fix this? I am using Tigervnc

Answer (score 0):

I change to xtightvncviewer instead and solved the problem